# Python if statement issue in kivy

Tags: python, if-statement, kivy

I'm using python in kivy on windows 10

```
spinner = Spinner(
    # default value shown
    text='-',
    # available values
    values=('Calendar', '2 Week Calendar', 'Calendar of Faces'),
    # positioning
    size_hint=(None, None),
    size=(100, 44),
    pos_hint={'center_x': .07, 'center_y': .96})

def show_selected_value(spinner, text):
    print('The spinner', spinner, 'has text', text)

spinner.bind(text=show_selected_value)

def MoveScreen(text):
    if text = "Calendar":
        sm.current = "Calendar"
```

I'm trying to use a spinner to change screens. The spinner by itself works, but when I add the if statement it doesn't. The error message points to the "=" after "text".

Answer (score 1):

`=` is for assignment. Use `==` like this:

```
if text == "Calendar":
    sm.current = "Calendar"
```